# A simple way to transform time series data inported from a relation database into a usable form in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, time-series, list-manipulation

I am trying to find a quick way to transform time series data imported from a relational database (from a single sql query) in the form

```
ticker     date   price      num_tickers num_dates
-------    ----   --------   ----------  ---------
t001       d1     pr001_d1    k           n    
t001       d2     pr001_d2    k           n     
...    
t001       dn     pr001_dn    k           n 
...
t002       d1     pr002_d1    k           n     
t002       d2     pr002_d2    k           n     
... 
t002       dn     pr002_dn    k           n 

...

t00k       d1     pr00k_d1    k           n     
t00k       d2     pr00k_d2    k           n     
... 
t00k       dn     pr00k_dn    k           n
```

(where I have included the last 2 columns so the number of tickers and dates are known without iterating through the data)

which gets imported into Mathematica in the form

```
data = {{'t001',d1,pr001d1,k,n},{'t001',d2,pr001d2,k,n},...,{'t001',dn,pr001dn,k,n},
{'t002',d1,pr002d1,k,n},{'t002',d2,pr002d2,k,n},...,{'t002',dn,pr002dn,k,n}
...
{'t00k',d1,pr00kd1,k,n},{'t00k',d2,pr00kd2k,k,n},...,{'t00k',dn,pr00kdn,k,n}}
```

But I need it in the form:

```
tickers = {'t001','t002',...,'t00k'}
dates =   {d1,d2,...,dn}
timeseries ={{pr001_d1,pr002_d1,...,pr00k_d1},
             {pr001_d2,pr002_d2,...,pr00k_d2},
             ...
             {pr001_dn,pr002_dn,...,pr00k_dn}}
```

I could do this by brute force looping through everything, but I know that Mathematica has some very powerful list manipulation functions (of which I'm not that familiar) and I was hoping that someone might know a slick way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split the data according to the first element, which is some kind of label. Use `SplitBy`, like so:

```
Module[{split=SplitBy[data,First]},
  tickers=split[[All,1,1]];
  dates=split[[1,All,2]];
  timeseries=split[[All,All,3]];]
```